# VLOOKUP or something like it in R

Tags: r, vlookup

Im very very new to R but i have got so far and i need help The data is for demo only but i need to be able to get the name from the room numbers, I can get it so I get the  then both to display but I just need the Name, in excel i would us vlookup

```
| Name     | room number  |
| -------- | -------------|
| Bob      | 1            |
| Jane     | 2            |
| Mike     | 3            |
| Second   | 4            |


Target = "1"
find_room <- dplyr::select(.data = bookings,
                        name ,
                        Room_no)

Room_no <- find_id[cheque_number == Target]

Room_no
```

Any help would
be great

Comment: `bookings %>% filter(Room_no == Target) %>% pull(Name)`; `with(bookings, Name[Room_no == Target])`

Comment: I think VLOOKUP is equivalent to `left_join()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a package that can create Excel functions: ExcelFunctionsR

However, Vlookup is a rubbish solution in Excel so you will be better using better functions in my opinion.  Excel wouldn't like looking up Name from RoomNo as it's to the left, for example.

```
MyData <- data.frame ( Name = c("John", "Jack", "Jane"), RoomNo = c(1, 4, 9))

Target = 4

Name <- MyData$Name[MyData$RoomNo == Target]

print(Name)
```

If you want to work at an individual level like that. (In R you will more commonly be adding columns...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bookings` is a dataframe containing `Name` and `room_number`, you can do as follows:

```r
bookings$Name[bookings$room_number == <Insert room number here>]
```

The above asks R to give you the `Name` column in the `bookings` dataframe and the expression

```r
bookings$room_number == <Insert room number here>
```

returns a logical vector marking the positions in the column `room_number` that contain the room number `<Insert room number here>`. This logical vector is used to indicate which elements of the `Name` column are desired.

You are trying to index elements from a dataframe. Please see these websites:

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Indexing_into_a_data_structure/
https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/r-data-frames/